# Maya Python API - help making a custom parent constraint node

Tags: python, api, matrix, maya

I'm trying to beef up my knowledge of the maya API (atm just in python, havent broached c++ yet) and as an exercise, I want to create a basic little parent constraint node - takes input of a source, a parent inverse and an offset matrix. I tested the maths first visually in the node editor:

[Node Network img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sKHv.png)

Essentially I'm just multiplying the offset matrix by the new parent's world mtx, and the world inverse matrix of the target's parent. Fairly standard, and the maths is visualised in the above graph, which does work! The target follows the source as expected.

The intention is to replace that multmatrix node with my own custom node that does exactly what that multMatrix is doing. Pointless? Maybe. Educational? 100%.

This is the compute code for the node:

```
    def compute(self, plug, data):
        if plug == AmysMathsNode.output_obj:
          
            source = data.inputValue(AmysMathsNode.source_obj).asMatrix()
            parentInverseMtx = data.inputValue(AmysMathsNode.parentInverseMtx_obj).asMatrix()
            offset = data.inputValue(AmysMathsNode.offset_obj).asMatrix()
            
            output = offset * source * parentInverseMtx

            output_data_handle = data.outputValue(AmysMathsNode.output_obj)
            output_data_handle.setMMatrix(output)

            data.setClean(plug)
```

But, when I plug in the same matrices from the multmatrix into my new node, it doesn't work. The target doesn't follow the source for one thing, and the values being output by the node are wacky for another. The scale, for some reason, is being set to zero, or strange values. The translation is also incorrect. These are the values i'm getting from the output matrix:

[custom node output values img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWXAs.png)

For reference, here are the values I was getting from the original node network that used a multMatrix instead of my custom node - these are what I'm expecting to be output from my node as well:

[multmatrix output values img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Qk6.png)

So my question is - what's up with that? Is there anything I've missed in the compute, in terms of making that maths run correctly? Is there anything obvious that would stand out as a reason why my custom node is not doing the exact same maths as the multmatrix?
Happy to post more of the node code if further context would help

Any help anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You should post your initialize method code as well. Sometimes it's simply you forgot to associate inputs to affect outputs (attributeAffects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used the API, but IIRC matrices are a bit of a nonsense in the API. In my foggy distant memory, I think you might need to use MFnMatrixData to access the data here?

First thing I'd do is check the value you are getting here is actually correct:

```cpp
            source = data.inputValue(AmysMathsNode.source_obj).asMatrix()
```

If that value looks suspect, then replace the call for asMatrix with asMObject, and pass the returned object to the MFnMatrixData constructor and see if that returns useful info?

I also suspect this line might be incorrect?

```cpp
output_data_handle.setMMatrix(output)
```

IIRC, you probably want to use MFnMatrixData::create, and pass the returned MObject to

```cpp
output_data_handle.setMObject(output)
```